# Route for a controller without model in rails 3

Tags: ruby-on-rails, model, controller, routes

I have a controller named `BaseController` that inherits from `ApplicationController` whitout a model associated but it has `ping` method that just respond with a message to inform that everything is OK.

I'm trying to call the action ping through the BaseController setting this in my routes.rb file:

```
namespace :api, defaults: { format: 'json' } do   
  match '/ping' => 'base#ping' 
end
```

But it always give me an NameError `uninitialized constant Base`. I suppose it's trying to find a model called Base which doesn't exist so, I don't know how to set to the correct route to my controller.

The content of my BaseController is the following:

```
class Api::BaseController < ApplicationController
   load_and_authorize_resource
   respond_to :json

   def ping
      respond_with({ :status => 'OK' })
   end
end
```

As extra information: `BaseController` is just a parent controller for other controllers to inherit. The others are resourceful controllers and have models associated

Thanks.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

When you put a namespace around a route, it will look for the controller within that namespace.

So in you case, it will be looking for a controller called Api::BaseController, which normally would be stored in app/controllers/api/base_controller.rb. Is this how your controller is set up?

See here for more details: http://guides.rubyonrails.org/routing.html#controller-namespaces-and-routing

**EDIT:**

I don't think its not finding the controller that's the problem. The error is being caused because you are calling `load_and_authorize_resource` in the controller.  CanCan uses the controller name to attempt to load the resource.

If there is no model for the controller, make the call `authorize_resource :class => false`.

See the [bottom of this page](https://github.com/ryanb/cancan/wiki/Non-RESTful-Controllers) for more details.

Comment: Can you add the contents of your `BaseController` to the question?

Comment: Thanks, for your interest. BaseController content added.

Comment: Updated answer, i think its due to how you are using CanCan.

Comment: Thanks a lot, that was exactly the problem.

Comment: No worries, goes to show its always good to put as much info as you can in your questions. :D Feel free to select this as the answer

Answer (score 0):

Please try this:

Add this in your routes.rb

```
resources :base
```

Comment: Thanks but stills the NameError, but I have not a base model, just a specific controller for an api. The controllers that inherit from BaseController works fine but they have models associated. I mean, the ping route wouldn't have to be a resourceful route.

Answer (score 0):

Try this in your routes.rb
map.resources :base, :collection=> {:ping=>:get}